# Strategies to query efficiently in HBase

Tags: hbase

I've designed HBase table where my `rowkey` is driven to the queries that I need to run on it. Following the best practices I included a hashed portion as prefix of my rowkeys, trying to spread the rows as much uniform as possible across my table regions.

I'm concerned about the following scenario:

I got billions of rows in my HBase table split between 3 regions. I'm using this table to provide data for a REST API, and because that, it needs to provide the rows as fast as possible.

Unfortunately, I'm hitting the famous timeout error `Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms` even if I invoke either `count "table_name"` in the hbase shell or for any other scan including `startrow` and `stoprow` parameters.It seems scanning by ranges using the `rowkey` is sweeping the whole hbase table.

Considering this scenario I'd like to ask 2 questions:

1) Is there any strategy to really retrieve range of rows as fast as possible without hitting the timeout error? I really appreciate any pointers here.

2) As I'm new in HBase, do you think HBase is the best or at least adequate solution to provide fast retrieval data to a REST API, considering the search are in fact scans by range of rowkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Increase the number of region servers
2. Increase the number of regions
3. Number of regions per region server should be of order of 50 not more than that for very fast response.
4. If possible spawn region server on all data nodes on your cluster. Do not run region servers in isolation

If your data size is not huge , you can try using Aerospike its best suited for API , as it provides millisecond latency for get and put.

To Know about Hbase in details :
http://bytepadding.com/hbase/